# How to implement actions in ST-monad with my own underlying representation (similarly to STRef or STArray) using simple techniques?

Tags: haskell, ffi, mutable, state-monad

I want to manipulate structs of a certain type from FFI through an interface like that provided with `STArray` or `STRef` in an `ST` monad. I'll have my own specific methods with understandable names for the kind of manipulations that are useful for this struct (like `readArray` and `writeArray` for arrays).

What is the simplest way to implement this?

The implementation for `STArray` (based on https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/src/GHC-Arr.html) looks too convoluted for those who do not know some special GHC techniques used for this.

Can I write something on a more simple, understandable level of Haskell?

#### Remarks

I'm not asking about how to access a struct through FFI.

I'd rather write getter and setter functions in C, and I want to mirror them in Haskell (to get ST-actions like `readArray` and `writeArray`).

#### Some thoughts on easy declaration of this kind of interface (a possible GHC extension?)

If I'm not mistaken, I can declare a foreign function as either an IO-action or pure (if I'm sure it is pure). I understand the latter as simply shortcutting wrapping it in `unsafePerformIO`:

```
foreign import ccall safe "getValue.h getValue" effect :: CInt -> Ptr CChar
foreign import ccall safe "getValue.h getValue" pure :: CInt -> IO (Ptr CChar)
```

So, the idea arises that an **intermediate form between "effect" and "pure"** could be possible, to save programmer's work. An "effect" limited to a "limited state":

```
foreign import ccall safe "getValue.h writeValue" writeValue :: (ValueRef s) -> Value -> ST s () -- modeled after writeSTRef
```

in addition to the standard two variants for this function in GHC:

```
foreign import ccall safe "getValue.h writeValue" writeValue :: ValueRef -> Value -> IO ()
foreign import ccall safe "getValue.h writeValue" writeValue :: ValueRef -> Value -> () -- must be really bad!
```

I only can't get the details about `ValueRef` right: if we define this unparameterized type, then how can the compiler use a parameterized one to give an ST-action?..

Probably, this is not available in GHC, but could be useful extension, couldn't it?

Comment: C Arrays and "native" Haskell STArrays are different things. Typically you use `IO`, not `ST` when working with FFI. If you are really sure your C functions have no externally observable side effects, and you wish to bring the FFI into ST, you will probably need to write the functions with the FFI and then use `unsafeIOToST` (in Control.Monad.ST.Unsafe).

Comment: @user2407038 Ah, ok, thanks! I was probably looking for `unsafeIOToST`.

Comment: @user2407038 BTW, [What is the difference between `ioToST` and `unsafeIOToST` from GHC.IO?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28769550/94687)

Comment: I don't believe that you can get the FFI to marshal your functions directly to ST s, instead of IO. It would be useful in this case certainly, but I don't know if there are many people with this use case. You can certainly submit a feature request!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Based on my comment, I'll give a short example of how this can be done.

First start with your basic C module.

```
typedef struct { int bar; int baz; } foo ;

foo * newFoo ();

void freeFoo (foo * ) ;

int readBar ( foo * ) ;
int readBaz ( foo * ) ;

void writeBar ( foo * , int ) ;
void writeBaz ( foo * , int ) ;
```

Then the Haskell file.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}

import Foreign.C
import Control.Monad.ST
import Control.Monad.ST.Unsafe
import Foreign.Ptr 
import Foreign.ForeignPtr 
import Control.Applicative

data Foo = Foo { bar :: Int, baz :: Int }
```

And all of your foreign imports.

```
foreign import ccall "newFoo" c_newFoo :: IO (Ptr Foo) 
foreign import ccall "&freeFoo" p_freeFoo :: FunPtr (Ptr Foo -> IO ())

foreign import ccall "readBar" c_readBar :: Ptr Foo -> IO CInt 
foreign import ccall "readBaz" c_readBaz :: Ptr Foo -> IO CInt 

foreign import ccall "writeBar" c_writeBar :: Ptr Foo -> CInt -> IO ()
foreign import ccall "writeBaz" c_writeBaz :: Ptr Foo -> CInt -> IO ()
```

In case you need to do something special on the C side but don't want to have to force your user to call `free` on your `Foo`, you can use a `ForeignPtr` in your actual representation.

```
data STFoo s = STFoo (ForeignPtr Foo)
```

Of course, this type must be abstract. If you are on GHC 7.8 or later, you should also include

```
{-# LANGUAGE RoleAnnotations #-} -- at the top

type role STFoo nominal
```

or people may be able to break the invariants you get from `ST`. When you create a new `STFoo`, you want to put the C side finalizer on it.

```
newFoo :: ST s (STFoo s) 
newFoo = STFoo <$> unsafeIOToST (c_newFoo >>= newForeignPtr p_freeFoo)
```

Reading and writing is basically just some coercions.

```
readBar :: STFoo s -> ST s Int
readBar (STFoo x) = fromIntegral <$> unsafeIOToST (withForeignPtr x c_readBar)

writeBar :: STFoo s -> Int -> ST s () 
writeBar (STFoo x) i = unsafeIOToST $ withForeignPtr x $ \p -> 
                       c_writeBar p (fromIntegral i)
```

You can also get a Haskell side Foo value, which will likely be the result of a computation inside ST. This is like `freezeSTArray`.

```
freezeFoo :: STFoo s -> ST s Foo 
freezeFoo (STFoo x) = unsafeIOToST $ withForeignPtr x $ \p -> do 
  bar <- fromIntegral <$> c_readBar p
  baz <- fromIntegral <$> c_readBaz p 
  return (Foo bar baz)
```

This all comes with the caveat that if your C functions are not exception safe or violate referential transparency, the Haskell type system will not help you, and you may end up exposing `unsafePerformIO`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is very clear and helpful. I don't understand why you use `Ptr Foo` for typing the pointers, because `Foo` is the *analoguous* Haskell data type, but I don't believe that the C struct and the Haskell data have the same in-memory representation. `Foo` even has `Int` inside, not `CInt`. Of course, the parameter to `Ptr` doesn't make much difference in reality and only serves not to mix pointers to different types, but isn't the choice of `Foo` as the parameter confusing?

Comment: I'd make the arguments of `writeBar` the other way round: like in `c_writeBar` (and the examples of signatures I've updated my question with); that order would match `writeSTRef :: STRef s a -> a -> ST s ()` and `writeArray :: (MArray a e m, Ix i) => a i e -> i -> e -> m ()`

Comment: The reason that `Ptr Foo` is "correct" is because the type parameter to `Ptr` is a phantom type; no actual `Foo` is stored inside of it (it looks like `data Ptr a = Ptr Addr#`, where Addr# is the primitive type of pointers and is basically just Word64). No "magic" happens to convert the c-struct to a Haskell type. I used `Ptr Foo` because morally `Ptr Foo` is a pointer to a value of type `Foo` - the fact that `Ptr Foo` doesn't represent its data with the same memory layout as `Foo` itself isn't relevant. Of course, you can pick a different type if you find it helps clarity (`Ptr CFoo`).

Comment: As for the order of arguments, that doesn't really relate to the content of the question - it is more style. If you think it would help readability or understanding for future readers, please feel free to edit the answer.

Comment: Sure, it's just style, and no real drawback. If you don't mind, I'll swap them to match the example from standard library.

Comment: Another tiny stylistic issue for me was that `STArray` and `STRef` have ST prefixed, but `FooST` has it as a postfix. Are there some (stylistic) reasons to do it one or another way?

Comment: Also just an arbitrary style choice. I threw together the example quite quickly so I wasn't thinking about those details. If you think of any small issues like this, please make any appropriate edits.