# What is the difference between `ioToST` and `unsafeIOToST` from GHC.IO

Tags: haskell, io, ghc, state-monad

What can the differences and intended uses be for `ioToST` and `unsafeSTToIO` defined in [GHC.IO](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/src/GHC-IO.html)?

```
-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Coercions between IO and ST

-- | A monad transformer embedding strict state transformers in the 'IO'
-- monad.  The 'RealWorld' parameter indicates that the internal state
-- used by the 'ST' computation is a special one supplied by the 'IO'
-- monad, and thus distinct from those used by invocations of 'runST'.
stToIO        :: ST RealWorld a -> IO a
stToIO (ST m) = IO m

ioToST        :: IO a -> ST RealWorld a
ioToST (IO m) = (ST m)

-- This relies on IO and ST having the same representation modulo the
-- constraint on the type of the state
--
unsafeIOToST        :: IO a -> ST s a
unsafeIOToST (IO io) = ST $ \ s -> (unsafeCoerce# io) s

unsafeSTToIO :: ST s a -> IO a
unsafeSTToIO (ST m) = IO (unsafeCoerce# m)
```

Comment: The difference is in the types. ioToST can only produce an `ST RealWorld a` which you cannot pass to `runST :: (forall s . ST s a) -> a`.

Answer (score 12):

The safe versions must start in the IO monad (because you cannot obtain an `ST RealWorld` from `runST`) and allow you to switch between the IO context and a `ST RealWorld` context. They are safe because `ST RealWorld` is basically the same thing as IO.

The unsafe versions can start anywhere (because `runST` can be called anywhere) and allow you to switch between an arbitrary ST monad and the IO monad. Using `runST` from a pure context and then doing a `unsafeIOToST` within the state monad is basically equivalent to using `unsafePerformIO`.

Comment: I know it's not the OP's question, but in my mind the bigger question is what, if anything, makes `unsafeSTToIO` unsafe.

Comment: @dfeuer It could either be called unsafe just for symmetry with `unsafeIOToST`, or maybe you can find a way to use it to access a `STVar` outside its `runST` wrapper, in which case it would be really unsafe all by itself.

Comment: I found a thread on haskell-cafe about it. It seems it really is unsafe, but I don't understand any of the examples.

Answer (score 11):

**TL;DR**. All four of these functions are just typecasts. They are all no-op at run-time. The *only* difference between them is the type signatures — but it's the type signatures that enforce all the safety guarantees in the first place!

---

The `ST` monad and the `IO` monad both give you mutable state.

It is famously impossible to escape the `IO` monad. [Well, no, you *can* if you use `unsafePerformIO`. Don't do that!] Because of this, all the I/O that your program will ever perform gets bundled up into a single giant `IO` block, thus enforcing a global ordering on the operations. [At least, until you call `forkIO`, but anyway...]

The reason `unsafePerformIO` is so damned unsafe is that there is *no way* to figure out exactly when, if, or how many times the enclosed I/O operations will happen — which is typically a *very bad thing*.

The `ST` monad also provides mutable state, but it *does* have an escape mechanism — the `runST` function. This lets you turn an impure value into a pure one. But now there is *no way* to guarantee what order separate `ST` blocks will run in. In order to prevent complete devastation, we need to ensure that separate `ST` blocks can't "interfere" with each other.

For that reason, you can't perform any I/O operations in the `ST` monad. You can access mutable state, but that state isn't allowed to escape the `ST` block.

The `IO` monad and the `ST` monad are actually *the same monad*. And an `IORef` is actually an `STRef`, and so on. So it would really by jolly useful to be able to write code and use it in both monads. And all four of the functions you mention are type-casts that let you do exactly that.

To understand the danger, we need to understand how `ST` achieves it's little trick. It's all in the phantom `s` type in the type signatures. To run an `ST` block, it needs to work for all possible `s`:

```
runST :: (forall s. ST s x) -> x
```

All the mutable stuff has `s` in the type as well, and by a happy accident, that means that any attempt to return mutable stuff out of the `ST` monad will be ill-typed. (This is really a bit of a hack, but it works so perfectly...)

At least, it will be ill-typed if you use `runST`. Notice that `ioToST` gives you an `ST RealWorld x`. Roughly speaking, `IO x` ≈ `ST RealWorld x`. But `runST` won't accept that as input. So you can't use `runST` to run I/O.

The `ioToST` gives you a type that you can't use with `runST`. But `unsafeIOToST` gives you a type that works just fine with `runST`. At that point, you have basically implemented `unsafePerformIO`:

```
unsafePerformIO = runST . ioToST
```

The `unsafeSTToIO` allows you to get mutable stuff out of one `ST` block, and potentially into another:

```
foobar = do
  v <- unsafeSTToIO (newSTRef 42)
  let w = runST (readSTRef v)
  let x = runST (writeSTRef v 99)
  print w
```

Wanna take a guess what is going to get printed? Because the thing is, we've got three `ST` actions here, which can happen in absolutely any order. Will the `readSTRef` happen before or after the `writeSTRef`?

[Actually, in this example, the write never happens, because we don't "do" anything with `x`. But if I pass `x` to some distant, unrelated part of the code, and that code happens to inspect it, suddenly our I/O operation does something different. Pure code shouldn't be able to affect mutable stuff like that!]

---

**Edit:** It appears I was slightly premature. The `unsafeSTToIO` function allows you to take a mutable value out of the `ST` monad, but it appears it requires a second call to `unsafeSTToIO` to put the mutable thing back *into* the `ST` monad again. (At that point, both actions are `IO` actions, so their ordering is guaranteed.)

You could of course mix in some `unsafeIOToST` as well, but that doesn't really prove that `unsafeSTToIO` by itself is unsafe:

```
foobar = do
  v <- unsafeSTToIO (newSTRef 42)
  let w = runST (unsafeIOToST $ unsafeSTToIO $ readSTRef v)
  let x = runST (unsafeIOToST $ unsafeSTToIO $ writeSTRef v 99)
  print w
```

I've played around with this, and I haven't yet managed to convince the type checker to let me do something provably unsafe using *only* `unsafeSTToIO`. I remain convinced it can be done, and the various comments on this question seem to agree, but I can't actually construct an example. You get the idea though; change the types, and your safety gets broken.

Comment: "So it would really by jolly useful to be able to write code and use it in both monads." There's actually a very clean way to accomplish this purpose without anything unsafe: [`primitive`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/primitive) offers a `PrimMonad` class with `ST s` and `IO` instances and just about everything you could want to write functions that can deal with either instance. These conversions are only needed to deal with the fact that many library functions are (unnecessarily) specific.

Comment: Er ... I just tried, and your program doesn't typecheck. The real examples seem to be rather more subtle.

Comment: I believe the `foobar` example can't work. The reason being that `runST` needs a polytyped value, while `v` is monotyped. Indeed, `unsafeSTToIO (newSTRef 42)` has type `forall s. IO (STRef s Int)`, and not `IO (forall s. STRef s Int)`.